# Could a cloud of hydrogen-1 or helium-4 turn into Bose–Einstein condensate when the universe reaches maximum entropy?

Tags: cosmology, entropy, quantum-entanglement, atoms, bose-einstein-condensate

Laboratories can cool clouds of hydrogen-1 and helium-4 respectively into Bose–Einstein condensate (BEC), while hydrogen-1 makes up 75% of all atomic matter in the observable universe and helium-4 makes up 24% of all atomic matter. Some of the clouds might never fall into a galactic black hole and always survive while the universe eventually reaches maximum entropy.

So far, I see no consensus for the eventual temperature of the universe when it reaches maximum entropy. Also, I see no consensus about whether any atoms will avoid the fate [of] falling into black holes. Likewise, I do not know if it is possible for any cloud of hydrogen-1 or helium-4 to turn into BEC when the universe reaches maximum entropy.

Reference for hydrogen-1 BEC
http://web.mit.edu/physics/greytak-kleppner/publications/LT22_Talk.pdf

Reference for helium-4 BEC
https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-019-12192-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have pondered my question and my own answer is *most likely yes*. Many respective clouds of hydrogen-1 and helium-4 will evade the fate of falling into a black hole and eventually cool enough to turn into Bose–Einstein condensate (BEC).

First, I read from NASA ["10 Questions You Might Have About Black Holes"](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/news/1068/10-questions-you-might-have-about-black-holes/) and question 4 answers that it is not possible for a massive black hole to consume an entire galaxy. This implies that many respective clouds of hydrogen-1 and helium-4 will evade the fate of falling into a black hole.

Second, I conjecture that the ever expanding observable universe will always approach absolute zero and eventually reach near absolute zero that will turn respective clouds of hydrogen-1 and helium-4 into BEC. I will carefully evaluate any argument that claims maximum entropy of the universe will not be cold enough for BEC, but I doubt I will find a convincing argument.